# SQL User Defined Function finding previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been tryimng to get data from a previous record in a dataset and use some data from that previous record. The records are linked my an asset ID and i think i am getting close but i need some expert advice now just to get over the final hurdle. 
Below is the statement i have come up with but i get an error and i can see where the error is coming from but i dont know how to get round it.
My Code is:

```
SELECT location,
(SELECT TOP (1) week_number
 FROM dbo.tbl_job_planning AS l2
 WHERE week_number < dbo.tbl_job_planning.week_number
 ORDER BY week_number DESC) AS prev_week
FROM  dbo.tbl_job_planning
WHERE fleet_no = @fleet AND week_number = prev_week
ORDER BY date_starting DESC
```

The problem is that prev_week is not an actual column in my table it is made 'on the fly'. Please ca someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL Query to reference previous rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553825/tsql-query-to-reference-previous-rows)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH data_with_rn AS
(
  SELECT location, fleet_no, week_number,
       ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY fleet_no, ORDER BY week_number DESC) as week_rn
  FROM dbo.tbl_job_planning
)
SELECT base.location, base.date_starting, prior.week_number as prev_week
FROM data_with_rn base
LEFT JOIN data_with_rn prior ON prior.week_rn = base.week_rn - 1  AND base.fleet_no = prior.fleet_no
WHERE base.fleet_no = @fleet
ORDER BY base.date_starting DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid self-joining by using [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256(v=sql.110).aspx) function (available from SQL Server 2012):

```
with WeekOrder AS (
    select C.location, C.fleet_no, C.date_starting, LAG(location, 1, NULL) OVER (Partition By fleet_no Order By week_number Asc) AS PrevLocation
    FROM dbo.tbl_job_planning C
)
select * 
from  WeekOrder C
Where       C.fleet_no = @fleetNo
    and PrevLocation IS NOT NULL
Order By    C.date_starting Desc
```

Also, the query is a little smaller and should have a better execution plan than self-join versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can order the weeks by using a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowed function with a partition on the `fleet_no`.

This should work for you:

```
;With WeekOrder As
(
    Select  *, Row_Number Over (Partition By fleet_no Order By week_number Asc) As Row_Number
    From    tbl_job_planning
)
Select      C.location, P.week_number As Prev_week
From        WeekOrder   C
Left Join   WeekOrder   P   On  C.Row_Number - 1 = P.Row_Number
                            And C.fleet_no = P.fleet_no
Where       C.fleet_no = @fleet
Order By    C.date_starting Desc
```